# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: reportUnusedDeclaredThrownExceptionIncludeDocCommentReference

Tags: java, javascript, exception, gwt, smartgwt

I got **Exception**

`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: reportUnusedDeclaredThrownExceptionIncludeDocCommentReference outside eclipse in command line using maven.`

The **gwt** libraries are declared at the top of list of dependencies and **GWT 2.5.1** is being used.
How to solve this issue? Please help

Comment: It looks like you're using Maven -- when are you getting this error (please provide some more context)?

Comment: I get this error when it is compiling the gwt codes using the maven gwt plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I figured out what is the problem. 
In my pom.xml , I have this dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
<artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
<version>4.7.0</version>
```

The problem with this is that, jasper reports has a dependency on jdtcore

```
        <dependency>
        <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
        <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

jdtcore actually creates a conflict with the gwt compiler. To solve this problem, I need to add an exclusion in the jasper dependency like this

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
                <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Now if still need the jdtcore library in the web app (normally to dynamically compile jasper reports) we can add the dependency with scope runtime like this

```
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
        <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Last note, if anybody gets the problem, then should look if any dependency in pom.xml has got a dependency on jdtcore, exclude it and include it as runtime

Hope this helps

Comment: For gradle exclude transitive dependency as follows:

dependencies {
    compile('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:3.7.4') {
        //Exclude as it caused problems with GWT:
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991063/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-reportunuseddeclaredthrownexceptionincludedoccomment
        exclude group: 'eclipse', module: 'jdtcore'  
    }  
}

Answer (score 0):

For gradle exclude transitive dependency as follows in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:3.7.4') {
        //Exclude as it caused problems with GWT:
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991063/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-reportunuseddeclaredthrownexceptionincludedoccomment
        exclude group: 'eclipse', module: 'jdtcore'  
    }  
}
```

Except after I made this change my jasper compilation fails. I am not sure yet how can I get Jasper compilation and GWT compilation to coexist in same project?